# Pandas - dense rank but keep current group numbers

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm dealing with pandas dataframe and have a frame like:

```
data = {
  "name": ["Andrew", "Andrew", "James", "James", "Mary", "Andrew", "Michael"],
  "id": [3, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

----------------------

     name  id
0  Andrew   3
1  Andrew   3
2   James   1
3   James   0
4    Mary   0
5  Andrew   0
6  Michael  2
```

I'm trying to write code to group values by "name" column. However, I want to keep the current group numbers.
If the value is 0, it means that there is no assignment.
For the example above, assign a value of **3** for each occurrence of Andrew and a value of **1** for each occurrence of James. For Mary, there is no assignment so assign next/unique number.

The expected output:

```
     name  id
0  Andrew   3
1  Andrew   3
2   James   1
3   James   1
4    Mary   4
5  Andrew   3
6  Michael  2
```

I've spent time already trying to figure this out. I managed to get to something like this:

```
df.loc[df["id"].eq(0), "id"] = ( df['name'].rank(method='dense').astype(int))
```

The issue with above it that it ignore records equal 0, thus numbers are incorrect. I removed that part (values equal to 0) but then numbering is not preserved.

Can u please support me?

Comment: what exactly is the input, where is the third "Andrew" coming from?

Comment: @mozway - just edited my question. Sorry, I modified the df itself but forgot to modify "display" version.

Comment: thanks for the clarification, I provided [a suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71936010/16343464)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `0` values to missing values, so if use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) with `first` get all existing values instead them and then replace missing values by [`Series.rank`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.rank.html) with add maximal `id` and converting to integers:

```
df = df.replace({'id':{0:np.nan}})
df['id'] = df.groupby('name')['id'].transform('first')

s = df.loc[df["id"].isna(), 'name'].rank(method='dense') + df['id'].max()
df['id'] = df['id'].fillna(s).astype(int)
print (df)
      name  id
0   Andrew   3
1   Andrew   3
2    James   1
3    James   1
4     Mary   4
5   Andrew   3
6  Michael   2
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC you can first fill in the non-zero IDs with [`groupby.transform('max')`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) to get the max existing ID, then complete the names without ID to the next available ID on the masked data (you can use `factorize` or `rank` as you wish):

```
# fill existing non-zero IDs
s = df.groupby('name')['id'].transform('max')
m = s.eq(0)
df['id'] = s.mask(m)

# add new ones
df.loc[m, 'id'] = pd.factorize(df.loc[m, 'name'])[0]+df['id'].max()+1
# or rank, although factorize is more appropriate for non numerical data
# df.loc[m, 'id'] = df.loc[m, 'name'].rank(method='dense')+df['id'].max()

# optional, if you want integers
df['id']= df['id'].convert_dtypes()
```

output:

```
      name  id
0   Andrew   3
1   Andrew   3
2    James   1
3    James   1
4     Mary   4
5   Andrew   3
6  Michael   2
```